# How to setup email smarthost?

Tags: email-server

I'am looking for some help as I can not find any documentation on the internet as to how to do this. I want to setup a smart-host for email relaying.

Just to be clear, I am not looking for help on how to setup a sattelite MTA to relay emails via an external smart-host, that part I know. What I want to do is to to build and configure the actual smart-host that does the relaying.

I have found a ton of information online on how to setup an MTA to relay via a smart-host but can not find anything on how to setup the actual smart-host (email gateway) that does the relaying.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Or if anyone could point me towards some documentation on how to do this that would be wonderful.

Ragards, Mike.

Comment: What you need to do is to install your SMTP server of choice and configure it as a relay server. How you do that depends on your choice of SMTP server. Since you haven't told us that, we can't help. Additionally, your question is off topic here as it's essentially asking us to provide a "how to".

Comment: @joeqwerty Im trying to achieve this using postfix. I'm sorry if this may seem off topic, but i cant find any documentation on this setup. I'm really not looking for a "how to" just looking for someone to point me in the right direction. Would you by any chance know where i could find some documentation on the subject? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you are using Postfix:

- Frequently smart hosts are configured to use IP-address whitelists which you configure with the [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) parameter. Then any host with an ip-address in that whitelist can use your Postfix server as the SMTP relay / smarthost to send e-mail messages without further authentication.

Examples:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 168.100.189.0/28
mynetworks = !192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.0/28
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 168.100.189.0/28 [::1]/128 [2001:240:587::]/64
```

- Alternatively rather than securing relay priviliges with IP-address whitelists the smart host can be configured to require authentication. See the [Postfix SASL HowTo](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) for that. Then any SMTP client that authenticates can send mail to non-local addresses.